# VBA: copy whole column content starting for a specific and and the data below it

Tags: vba, excel

the thing is I want to copy a certain column but I want to only copy data on a specific cell and get the data below it.

Let say for example, I want to copy Cell C5 and below, this will disregard C1 to C4. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Find the last row using [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba/11169920#11169920) and then create you range. For Example `Range("C5:C" & LastRow)` and then simply copy it :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout I get a heavy load time, is this normal?

Comment: No. It should not take that long. See the answer that I posted below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further to my comments below your question, here is one way. This will work in all scenarios. Whether you have blank cells or not...

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyCells()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim sRow As Long, lRow As Long

    '~~> Change this to the relevant worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    sRow = 5 '<~~ Starting row

    With ws
        '~~> Find last row in Col C
        lRow = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> If the last row < Start Row
        If lRow < sRow Then
            MsgBox "Start Row cannot be greater then last row"
        Else
            '~~> Create your range
            Set rng = .Range("C" & sRow & ":C" & lRow)

            '~~> Copy
            rng.Copy

            '
            ' Do what you want with copied data
            '
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: it will not work in all scenarios. Consider there is a separate table/data under the desired range of data. Then it will also get those cells underneath the necessary range. That's what I was trying to refer but obviously OP has tabular data, so this will work without problem in this scenario.

Comment: Posting from phone: Obviously if there is another table then it won't. For that then you have to change '.rows.count' to a hard coded value ;) in both cases it is still advisable to use 'xlUp'

Answer (score 0):

```
Sheet1.Columns(3).Resize(Sheet1.Columns(3).Rows.Count - 4).Offset(4).Select
```

This will select entire C column but first 4 cells. It simply take column 3, resize it to subtract first 4 cells and offset the starting cell 4 cell below and select that range.
If your range is defined then code could be more optimized.

EDIT for sample code:

```
Sub copyCells()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim rngStart As Range
Dim rng As Range
    Set sht = Sheet1
    Set rngStart = sht.Cells(5, 3) ' this is C5
    rngStart.Select
    Set rng = rngStart.Resize(rngStart.End(xlDown).Row - rngStart.Row + 1)

    rng.Copy Sheet2.Cells(1, 1) ' copy where you need
End Sub
```

Comment: The number of items could vary so the ranged cannot be defined. Thanks for this!

Comment: try the sample code I just added. It assumes there is no blank cells in the range. If there is blanks then let me know.

Comment: @SiddharthRout, if there is no blanks then it is right way. I don't have enough info about the data structure, so I have to make assumptions. There might be other data under the desired data after spaces. That's why I didn't show xlUp from the bottom of the range. And I explained this in my comment.

Comment: `I don't have enough info about the data structure` Yup and hence to be safe use `xlup` You may want to see the link that I posted below OP's question?

Comment: Yea there is no blank spaces @smozgur

Comment: @ayasocool: then you can test my code. 
One thing I forgot to delete after testing in my code: remove rngStart.Select line since it is just for testing purposes.

Answer (score -1):

This will copy a entire column (with data) from selection, just paste it wherever you want.

```
Sub CopyColumnFromSelected()
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
End Sub
```

Or (Ctrl + Shift + down arrow) <--- from your desired cell and Ctrl+C    ;)

Comment: `xlDown` is highly unreliable. Also avoid the use of `.Select` You may want to see [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)